# aws credentails to work in container which is installed in EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-cli

I have a IAM Role , when attached to EC2 instance , i could use "AWSCLI S3" commands like : aws s3 ls,aws s3 cp s3://path etc.

Now had installed Docker in that EC2 instance. In container , need to use that AWS CLI commands which i used in EC2 instance.

Found below answers:
Use environment variables with aws keys while launching container.But this might be security risk, as AWS Keys could be visible.

Request you to suggest on this in more secure way

Comment: If you believe that passing ec2 credentials to the instance via environment variables is insecure, you may like to run on the instance the following command `curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/identity-credentials/ec2/security-credentials/ec2-instance/` You will see that the instance credentials are there for anything running on that instance "free to grab". The key part is to not expose them outside of the instance. Also, they expire every couple of hours.

Comment: All of the standard AWS SDKs know how to find per-instance temporary credentials at this URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Iam Role is good for the whole ec2 including the docker inside. You do not need to pass along the aws keys, just use the role.
For the commands you need to install the awscli:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-cliv2.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using host only networking on the container, the container will effectively inherit the IAM role of the instance. Try and run `curl http://169.254.169.254/2014-11-05/meta-data/iam/security-credentials` from the container itself. If you get a valid response, then you can use the CLI with the same permissions as the instance.